# Angular2 set height to full screen

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I would like to set a div to full screen in angular2 template

I have tried this
Im my html template

```
<div class="auth-container">

</div>
```

In trhe css

```
.auth-container{
  height: 100%; //also tried with min-height
  background-image: url("assets/images/backgroundimage.jpg");
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

}

THe image stretches to full screen but its cut off by the page height as shown in the screen shot below

Setting the height manually like

```
height:550px;
```

Stretches to full screen but its not responsive in different screen sizes

What do i need to set to extend the height to maximum

Comment: Is this question is related to angular?

Comment: This is related to HTML and CSS not angular you are just using angular template

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use may use `vh` (viewport-height) and `vw` (viewport-width) length units to stretch to full available screen size:

```
.auth-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

edit - Explanation: By using the css length unit % on height, you specify the height of the div relative to its parents height. Therefore, if the immediate parent (e.g.) has a smaller height than the viewport, it will not be enough. Only if you'd set all ancestor elements (html, body, ..., .auth-container) to height 100%, it would work this way.

Answer (score 3):

You could utilize the vh and vw units, so,

```
height: 100vh 
width: 100vw
```

Here's some good follow up reading that goes through the pros and cons of this method https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show top part of image simply use,

```
background-position-y: 0;
```

Since using cover property it will cut off a portion of your background.

also `background-size: 100% 100%;` for full image with responsive.